# About a point in the proof of Bernstein's inequality in "Introduction to Harmonic Analysis" by Katznelson

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

There is proof of Bernstein's inequality (page 33) in Katznelson's book, Introduction to Harmonic Analysis. The proof starts with if $h=2\pi/(3\cdot2^m)$ and $2^m \leq n \leq 2^{m+1}$ for $m \geq 0$, then we have $|e^{-inh}-1| \geq \sqrt{3}$. Why is this true? I have tried writing the exponential in terms on sines and cosines, but I have no idea how to proceed. I think this should be something relatively easy to show but cannot seem to get there. Any help is welcomed!

Comment: Which Bernstein inequality ? [This one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_(polynomials)#Bernstein's_inequality)  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponent is of the form $i nh = i \lambda$ with $|\lambda - \pi| \le \pi/3$. Thus $\cos \lambda  \le -1/2 $ and
$$|e^{i \lambda} - 1|^2 = 2 - 2 \cos \lambda \ge 3 \, .
$$

Comment: Why is $|\lambda - \pi| \leq \pi/3$?

Comment: Because $2\pi/3 \le \lambda \le 4 \pi/3$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $\varphi = nh$. Then $\varphi \in [\frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{4\pi}{3}]$ as $2^m \leq n \leq 2^{m+1}$.

We have $$
f(\varphi) := \vert e^{-inh} - 1 \vert^2 = \vert 1 - e^{i\varphi} \vert^2
= (1 - \cos(\varphi))^2 + (\sin(\varphi))^2
$$ and
$$
f\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) = f\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) = \left(1-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2 + \left( \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2 = 3.
$$
In between, that means for $\varphi \in (\frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{4\pi}{3})$, the values of are always greater than that because of
$$
f'(\varphi) = 2 \sin(\varphi).
$$